# Meaning of "cheap out" in this context

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> Supercars are for the rich anyways so why **cheap out** by not having a
>   roll cage with harnesses?

cheap out - don't spend lots of money, or what does that mean?

Comment: Please add a link or remark in your question telling us where this sentence came from.

Comment: [Cheap out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cheap%20out): ": to be cheap with money : to spend less than should be spent in order to save money."